# Adding and Removing Fields Programmatically on Forms

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Sorry this isn't a specific coding question, it is more of a design concept.

What is the usage case for programmatically adding and removing fields to Notes Forms e.g. NotesDocument.RemoveItem(), ie why would you add and remove fields in the background?

For many years I have designed my forms with the fields layed out on the form which are required and then hide and show as required.

By adding dynamically you can't position them and frustratingly removing them or deleting they still appear the Database Fields in Domino Designer, getting rid of them is a bit a a black art, but that's another story.

I must be missing a trick or a basic design concept. Any thoughts on best practice would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are missing the difference between "Fields" and "Items". A field is a design element that you can place anywhere on your form. You define how it looks, what content it contains, what datatype it is, etc.

When creating a document with the form the value of the FIELD is stored in an ITEM in the resulting NotesDocument.

This item is totally decoupled from the field that created it. If you were to change the field in the form from text to number or move it around or make a names- field of it, the item in the existing documents would never change unless you open the documents and save them in frontend or use any LotusScript or Formula Code to recalculate the document in backend.

Very often items are added programmatically to documents to fulfill different purposes: Calculate values to be displayed in views, calculate values that are import for the workflow but not for the user, etc.

Complex applications often consist of a lot more items than there are fields in the several forms.

Back to your question: Removing an item from a document simply removes the value that was created by the field in the form. When reopening the document, the item will be repopulated, either by default value or whatever....

Usually you would use this to remove items that you no longer need (and probably already removed from the form).

As soon as you removed all references to a field / item everywhere in design and documents, you can finally get rid of it completely by compacting the database.

Answer (score 0):

An item is distinct from a field in Notes.  The form is purely a UI concept, the item is what the data is stored in.

Manipulating data in the backend can be used for a number of reasons.  One such use case is the setting of a flag when a date on the form has expired.

Say you want a view showing all documents that have expired.  Your rules dictate that documents are considered as "Expired" after 7 days.  You could create a view with a formula that shows all document whose date is 7 days older than today:

```
SELECT Date < @Adjust(@Today; 0; 0; -7; 0; 0; 0);
```

This view will ALWAYS be out of date and will constantly be updated by the server as it re-evaluates @Today.

Now, a better way would be to create an agent that runs daily that sets an item on the document to indicate that it has expired e.g.

```
@SetField("Expired"; 1);
```

The view formula would then be

```
SELECT Expired = 1
```

The view would only need to update daily and you have a much faster view because of it.

RemoveItem is used to get rid of data no longer needed e.g. FaxNumber.

Comment: Thank you Rob and Tode. I probably didn't explain fully, I am aware of the difference between the Field and an Item and the example above is one which I use, but with Lotusscript. The main difference being, like many of the templates, I have this type of field at the top of the form, hidden rather than created and remove. This seems a logical to me as I have visual reference of my items (fields).

Comment: I guess I am being overly concerned about creating lots of items which then need managing, am I looking at that wrong?

I hadn't thought of the removing to repopulate when opened again. I will use that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

There are many use cases for RemoveItem. Here's one that comes up frequently.

You have a database and an agent that processes documents in that database. Every time it runs, the agent replaces the value of a bunch of items. There are a variety of error conditions that can cause it to abort processing a document early, but you're a smart programmer and you've accounted for that with `on error` traps. When you hit one, you log an error message, save your document, and then either abort your agent or go on to processing the next document.

But at this point, some of the items that the agent normally updates have values saved from this run, and some of them have values saved from a previous run. This might be bad. This might be confusing for someone who is looking at the item values and trying to figure out what's going on. This might even cause validation errors on the form.

So how do you avoid this? At the very beginning of your agent, you call a cleanup sub that finds and removes all the items that the agent is going to update. Now you have a clean slate, and if your agent hits that error condition, it can save whatever it can save without any concern about whether it is leaving things in an inconsistent state. Of course, in cases where you are doing this to avoid validation errors, your validation formulas will have to be smart enough to be checking @IsAvailable for dependent items, but that's a good practice anyhow.